# List all macro calls

Tags: macros

Assume I have a big document that uses several macros, say `\AAA`, `\BBB`, etc., through the whole document.

Is there a way that I can have a list of all these macros in the final pdf? I want to repeat all the `\AAA` calls at the beginning for example, to have a very quick glance at them while writing the document.

An optional feature would use hyperref to click on one `\AAA` of the list to go directly on the pdf page where the macro is actually used.

Comment: `\tracingmacros`?

Comment: This seems overkill. I only want *some* macros, not all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could put a `\hypertarget` in every call of `\AAA`, where the name uses a counter. Afterwards you can reference it by `\hyperlink`.

In the example the `\AAA No. 1`, etc. are clickable links.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{pgffor,hyperref}
\newcount\countAAA
\countAAA=0
\newcommand*\AAA{%
    \advance\countAAA by 1%
    \hypertarget{AAA\the\countAAA}{}%
    AAA% your replacement text goes here
}
\newcommand\blindtext{\par\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \par\noindent}
\begin{document}
\section{Some text with \texttt{\string\AAA} macros}
\blindtext
\AAA
\blindtext
\AAA
\blindtext
\AAA
\blindtext
\AAA
\section{List of \texttt{\string\AAA} calls}
There are \the\countAAA\ calls of \texttt{\string\AAA} throughout the document.

\foreach \i in {1,...,\the\countAAA} {
    \hyperlink{AAA\i}{\texttt{\string\AAA} No.\ \i}
}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: @wwjoze You can also replace the `pgffor` package with `tikz`, if you need drawing functionality.